# How to access the Flask API running on my local system from another device (not connected to Wi-Fi)?

Tags: python, flask

How can I access the Flask API running on my local system (connected to Wi-Fi) from my phone (NOT connected to Wi-Fi)?

If the (simplified) code of my Flask API is:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def about():
    return 'It worked!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I can access the Flask API using my phone (connected to my Wi-Fi network) by typing in the browser search bar `http://[ip]:5000/`, where `[ip]` is the IP address of the computer the Flask API is running on.

Now I want to do the same test after disconnecting the phone from the Wi-Fi network. Then:

- I allowed TCP traffic on port 5000 (Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Inbound Rules > New Rule > ...) and
- I have disabled the firewall

but it still doesn't work. What else could I try?

Comment: What kind of IP address are you using? Are you maybe using a local IP address?

Comment: I'm using my IPv4 address

Comment: Does the IP address start with `192.168.`?

Comment: Yes, it starts with `192.168.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to find you public IP address and use that instead of the internal/local IP address, check for e.g. [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/117371/how-to-find-your-computers-private-public-ip-addresses/) or just search for "how to find my public ip address".

Comment: It still does not work. Is `host='0.0.0.0'` correct in `app.run()`?